# Jenkinsfile: Create a new file (Groovy)

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to write a `Jenkinsfile` with a stage that create a new file and use it later.

Whatever i do i get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./ci/new_file.txt (No such file or directory)
```

Here is the relevant code block:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Some Stage') {
            steps {
                script{
                    file = new File('./ci/new_file.txt').text
                    file.createNewFile()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I went over some similar questions and nothing has helped so far. 
Please advise.

Comment: Are you sure the 'ci' directory is there?  Your code doesn't mkdir it...

Comment: Yes, It's already created. This directory contains some scripts.

Comment: I would not think that `new File('foo.txt').text` would work since you are trying to access the content of a nonexistent file at that point, and the error message seems to agree with me.

Comment: So what can i do i order to work with files? (Create, read, etc).

Comment: Not attempt to immediately read the content of a nonexistent file or invoke a nonexistent method on the class (`createNewFile()` is not a method for the `File` class). Check here for helpful documentation: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/groovy/groovy_file_io.htm

Comment: For the casual reader: The file is not found because it looks in the wrong directory. It (".") is relative not to Jenkins workspace but to jvm's pwd(which I guess is "/" ). Make sure to give a correct (absolute) path and it should work. (Be aware of the security impact).

Answer (score 5):

You have not actually created the file and tried to read this one. You have to create file before using it.
For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Some Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    File file = new File('./ci/new_file.txt')
                    file.createNewFile()
                    //...
                    String fileText = ... read file
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this is not the best solution for you. It is better to use jenkins steps 'readFile' and 'writeFile'. Documentation is here - https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/ 
For example:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Some Stage') {
            steps {
                script {
                    writeFile file: "./ci/new_file.txt", text: "Some Text"
                    //...
                    String fileText = readFile file: "./ci/new_file.txt"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Your first example doesn't work (I get: `java.io.IOException: No such file or directory`). Your second example doesn't work as well (I get: `Expected named arguments but got [new_file.txt, some text]`).  The syntax should be: `writeFile file: "./ci/new_file.txt", text: "Some Text"` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Is your pipeline code executed on remote agent?

Cloudbees notes that `java.io.File` may not work in Pipeline and recommends using native pipeline steps to interact with files.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/230922128-Pipeline-Using-java-io-File-in-a-Pipeline-description

Comment: My pipeline is being executed locally the Jenkins server (Triggered on tag event).

Comment: @casual readers: well cloudbees is wrong(ish). File works(Omri uses it - you can try). But: Jenkins can do Sandboxing. If it does, "File" is considered insecure. You can see why if you understand Omri's problem: he was looking for his  files in the wrong directory! Probably "/" (the server's root - but YMMV) not the workspace(thats why the file isn't found). Sure even Sandboxed you can explicitely allow it("http//<servername>/scriptApproval") - that is, if you realy want to allow "some" Jenkinsfile from "some" Git FULL ACCESS to the server. Well ...

Answer (score -1):

I answered a similiar question a time ago. Here it is my answered code. Hope it can help you!

```
stage('My Stage'){
      steps{
            ...
            script{
                   writeFile file: 'groovy1.txt', text: 'Working with files the Groovy way is easy.'
                   sh 'ls -l groovy1.txt'
                   sh 'cat groovy1.txt' 
            }
       }
    }
```